# On Jenkins how can you detect if a server is Windows vs. Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, jenkins, operating-system

On Jenkins I'm using the Conditional BuildStep Plugin. Is there a way to have it run some build steps depending on whether or not the slave node it's running on is Windows vs. Linux?

Answer (score 5):

You can use **isUnix()** function available in jenkins for identifying the OS type.

So you can use something like below inside your jenkinsfile under script block:-

```
 if (isUnix()) {
    sh 'ls -la'
} else {
    bat 'dir'
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Good to know. But sometimes I need to know which OS it is in order to run a Windows Batch command versus a shell command. So I need to know outside of the script block. That's why I've been using the Conditional BuildStep Plugin.

Answer (score 2):

To run commands only if the current server is Windows, use the Conditional BuildStep Plugin to check:

```
Strings match:
 String 1: ${ENV,var="OS"}
 String 2: Windows_NT
```

And to run commands only if the current server is Linux, check:

```
Strings match:
 String 1: ${ENV,var="OS"}
 String 2:
```

(Leaving String 2 blank.)